# How can I get cleaner output from Ansible jobs?

Tags: ansible

I'm taking time this week to get up to speed on Ansible.

Despite having:

```
$ ansible-config dump | grep -i ^ans.*color
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR(default) = False
ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR(env: ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR) = True
```

I get ANSI-ish junk in my output:

```
...
resizewin: timeout reading from terminal
...
Shared connection to host.example.com closed.

^[[45;160R       25.22 real         2.64 user         1.49 sys
$ 5;160R5;160R5;160R5;160R
```

Also, is there any way to get **just** the `stdout` of the ansible job, without the Ansible artifacts

```
 host.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
```

and

```
Shared connection to host.example.com closed.
```

I can see that output has value in some situations, but in other situations I'd like to be able to capture just the `stdout`.  Presently, I'm resorting to `head` and `tail` tricks to strip the first line and the last two lines of the output, which works, but is tiresome.

```
$ ansible-config dump --only-changed
ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR(/usr/local/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) = True
DEFAULT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE(/usr/local/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) = /home/jim/.ssh/my-ansible-id_rsa
```

Comment: What other changes did you make to your ansible configuration?

Comment: Changes to your config are returned by `ansible-config dump --only-changed`

Answer (score 3):

Ad-hoc `ansible` output sometimes includes a dict of the return values, and warnings go to stderr. But the first line looks like something intended for human consumption not a machine. Plus you only get to run one task.

If you are parsing the results of a task at all, [write a playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) and run it with `ansible-playbook`. It may be short, that's fine.

```
- name: Do a thing
  register: result
  command: /bin/uptime

- name: Print result dict
  debug:
    var: result
```

Jinja expressions are available. Print out only the variable you care about (perhaps `result.stdout`), render a template, run another command based on stdout, or do any number of things with the result.